# Can't load a .NET type in PowerShell

Tags: reflection, powershell, assemblies

This is a strange one. I'm trying to load the `System.DirectoryServices` assembly and then create an instance of the `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry` class.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
PS C:> [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices")

GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
True   v2.0.50727     C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.DirectoryServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Directo...
```

It seems to have loaded the assembly fine, but now when I try to instantiate a new object it fails:

```
PS C:\> $computer = new-object [System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry]("WinNT://localhost,computer")
New-Object : Cannot find type [[System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry]]: make sure the assembly containing this type
is loaded.
At line:1 char:23
+ $computer = new-object <<<<  [System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry]("WinNT://localhost,computer")
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

However, if I try to do it in a slightly more obtuse way, it seems to work.

```
$directoryServices = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices")
$directoryEntryType = $directoryServices.GetType("System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry")
$machine = New-Object $directoryEntryType("WinNT://localhost,computer")
$machine
```

It shows me I've created the object successfully:

```
distinguishedName :
Path              : WinNT://localhost,computer
```

What's the proper way to do this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your [`new-object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347574.aspx) syntax is a little off. Try this:

```sh
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices")
$machine = new-object -typeName System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry -argumentList "WinNT://localhost,computer"
```

Comment: Yeah, using the C# style "constructor" is technically invalid in PowerShell. Use the -TypeName and -ArgumentList parameters on the New-Object cmdlet the way they were intended.

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to load anything. Use the adsi type accelerator:

```
[adsi]"WinNT://localhost,computer"
```

Comment: Is there any good documentation on it? Things don't seem very "discoverable"

Comment: Do a search for powershell type accelartors

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax for [New-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849885.aspx) is incorrect. Taken from [some documentation on New-Object]:[1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849885.aspx)

```
New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("WinNT://localhost,computer")
```